# Popular DropDownList a partir de outro

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mvc

Bom dia,

Tenho um DropDownList populado a partir de uma classe do Model.
exemplo: Processador, Memória, HD
[image: DropDownLisr Dinâmico]

Após clicar em "+" tenho que adicionar outro DropDownList com todos os valores menos o valor selecionado no Combo anterior.

```
   @if (Model.ListAtributoAtivo != null)
                {
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.idAtributo, Model.AtributosFiltroList, @Resource.Selecionar)
                    <a onclick="return add(this)"><img src="../../images/icon-3.png" alt="icon"></a>
                }
```

Já tentei usar o knout.js mas não é fácil implementar ele.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá, no código abaixo tem dois drop's onde o segundo é populado com todas as opções do primeiro menos a opção selecionada, espero que ajude.

```js
function popularOptions2() {
  $("#options1 option").each(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':selected')) {
      $("#options2").append("<option>" + $(this).val() + "</option>")
    }
  });
}

$("#populate").click(function() {
  popularOptions2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='options1'>
  <option>Teste 1</option>
  <option>Teste 2</option>
  <option>Teste 3</option>
</select>
<select id='options2'>
</select>
<button id='populate'>
  Populate
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando o método `clone()` você copia um elemento com todas as suas propriedades, ficando fácil de manipula-lo, no exemplo : https://jsfiddle.net/qk07Lg03/, eu clono um dropdown e seto a primeira `option` dele como `selected`, é possível fazer isso com qualquer elemento, como duplicar uma form inteira, por exemplo.

```
<select id='sl1'>
<option></option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
<button>
+
</button>


$("button").click(function(){
    var novoSl = $("#sl1").clone(true).insertBefore($(this));
  //Agora é possivel manipular o novo select como desejar;
  novoSl.find("option")[0].prop("selected", true);
})
```